# How to access weight property of a node in a force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Maybe this is a silly question but i'm a d3 newb.  I'm trying to change the radius of the circles in a force layout based on the source link weight.  Why is d.source.weight accessible within the tick function but not anywhere else?

E.g.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) {console.log(d.source.name + " " + d.source.weight; return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
```

returns the correct values to the console, but why aren't those properties accessible when appending the circles?

```
node.append("circle")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("r", function(d) {return d.source.weight * 2;});  // breaks
```

I feel like this is more of a basic javascript question than a d3 question, but i can't find much help on it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tick function isn't changing what happens when you set `.attr("r", ect )`; you're changing what you're setting:

**link**

```
link.attr("x1", function(d) {console.log(d.source.name + " " + d.source.weight; return d.source.x; })
```

**node**

```
  node.append("circle")
 .attr("class", "node")
 .attr("r", function(d) {return d.source.weight * 2;});  // breaks
```

I'm guessing you're working off of [this example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html). You can figure out how node are different by reading through lines 38-69 of the [source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference) while referencing the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference). That can be tricky and kind of a slog though; I would recommend opening the console with the example and playing around a little to get a better idea of what is going on.

I'd recommend trying a few of these commands (use chrome so you can also easily inspect the objects and see what attributes the data connected to node and link has):

```
node.attr("r", function(d){ return 8; })
node.attr("r", function(d){ return d.weight; })

link.attr("class", "")
link.attr("stroke", "yellow")
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did see in the docs that weight is an attribute of a node, and not a link.  In the case of node.append, I'm assuming that "d" is the node, in which case d.source.weight wouldn't work.  However, d.weight doesn't work either and i'm not sure why (returns "undefined").  d.source.weight i guess works within link.attr, because "d" is a link; so I guess it interprets d.source as a node, allowing you to access d.source.weight?  Maybe these are fundamental questions but the docs aren't clear on this (from what i could see).

Comment: Also, i didn't know of that example, but it is similar to what i'm trying to do.  There he is setting the radius attribute via the node.transition() method, which is a bit confusing to me (but i haven't done much with that function).

Comment: .transition() just adds animation. If you inspect 'link' and 'node', you'll see that they are an array of objects. If you open the array and look inside any of the objects, they all have a __data__ attribute which d will be equal to when you use .attr("r", function(d){ ... })

Answer (score 1):

```
node.append("circle")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("r", function(d) {return d.weight * 2;});  // breaks
```

just remove ".source" your are working with nodes in this case function(d){...} not with links.